# health check of falcon web service from eureka discovery server

Tags: python, gunicorn, netflix-eureka

eureka server is the discovery server which tracks wether services are alive or not. i am able to register my services to it but it automatically de registers it.

Please suggest me a way by which i can achieve it from falcon web service and unicorn server.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. ServerFault.com would be a better place for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can register your service again and again after an interval of time in which it is getting de register.

try this:
[auto execute a web service in falcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512483/auto-execute-a-web-service-in-falcon)

Comment: it can work but can you please elaborate.. or will it be efficient method to solve the problem